# Extract stdout from std::cout in C++

Tags: c++, iostream, stdio

I am trying to overload the `<<` operator for my *C++* class called *Box*. It is not trivial and inside the definition I have to access the `stdout` object of type `FILE*` which is corresponding to the `std::cout`. I need exactly this object since the interface of another code I will use in my operator (*GNU MPFR* library) requires this particular one. How can I extract it?

Simplified version below:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Box &box) {
    x = ??? // get the stdout from os
    mpfr_out_str(x, 10, 0, box.number, MPFR_RNDN);
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Use `fopencookie` and stream to `os` on linux. The most _portable_ way - create `mktemp()` a temporary `FILE*`, write to it, `rewind()` then `read()` to a buffer, then output to `os`. As for `How can I extract it?` the general answer is "don't".

Comment: `ostream` is not necessarily connected to a file, it could for example be a `ostringstream`.

Comment: This seems like asking for trouble. What if the `ostream` in question does not have an underlying `FILE *`?  You cannot rely on the first argument to be specifically `std::cout`.  If you must overload `<<` then `mpfr_out_str()` may not be an option for you.  Or perhaps it's overloading `<<` that you should give up on -- you could always write an ordinary method that takes the needed `FILE *` as an argument.  Of course, that mainly just pushes the problem off on the clients of your `Box`.

Comment: You might consider `mpfr_get_str` to format a string and then output that. https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#mpfr_005fget_005fstr